# Parsing an indentation-based syntax (like Python) with YECC

Tags: parsing, erlang, grammar, lalr, yecc

I have the following piece of code:

```
case 1
of 2
    3
of 3
    4
5
```

That my custom tokenizer translates to:

```
Tokens: [{'case',1},
         {integer,1,1},
         {eol,1},
         {'of',1},
         {integer,1,2},
         {block,[{integer,1,3}]},
         {eol,1},
         {'of',1},
         {integer,1,3},
         {block,[{integer,1,4}]},
         {eol,1},
         {integer,1,5}]
```

But then I'm not being able to parse it with the following Yecc:

```
Nonterminals
    grammar
    statements statement
    case_def case_conditions condition.


Terminals
    eol block
    integer
    case of.


Rootsymbol grammar.


grammar -> statements : '$1'.


statements -> statement eol statements : ['$1'|'$3'].
statements -> statement : ['$1'].

statement -> case_def : '$1'.
statement -> integer : '$1'.


case_def -> 'case' integer case_conditions : ''.

case_conditions -> case_condition case_conditions : ['$1'|'$2'].
case_conditions -> case_condition : ['$1'].

case_condition -> eol 'of' integer block : ''.
```

It gives me the following output:

```
["syntax error before: ","5"]
```

Any help is really welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in nonterminal list, you should have `case_condition` instead of `condition`.

Your custom scanner ignores the indentation. It has to emit tokens for `INDENT` and `DEDENT`. I've found [example in yacc](http://www.benbarbour.com/implementing-python-style-indention-syntax-using-flex-bison-or-lexyacc/). Then you can change your grammar to use those tokens.

Your example generates shift/reduce conflict. Documentation says, that:

> Shift/reduce conflicts are resolved in favor of shifting if there are
>   no operator precedence declarations.

It means, that when your parser is at the place denoted by `|`

```
of 3
    4|
5
```

and sees new line, there might be two options:

- this might be next `case_condition` so parser needs to keep going "shift" to read more
- this might be end of statement so parser needs to treat everything before as statement and put it on stack or in short "reduce"

Because those conflicts are always resolved to shift, you can't put next statement after you started case! You need to change your grammar. Work with it until `yecc:file/1` does not generate any warnings.

HINT: Indent everything inside case like this:

```
case 1
    of 2
        3
    of 3
        4
5
```

This way, you are clearly saying, that `case` is one statement and `5` is another. My knowledge about parsers got a little rusty, but I believe, that you wouldn't be able to write grammar that is able to differentiate between `case_condition` and `statement` with left to right parser, if you don't add indentation or some kind of terminator.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20180825170334/www.benbarbour.com/implementing-python-style-indention-syntax-using-flex-bison-or-lexyacc/